# How to copy single value to all fields in tabular form?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I want to copy single value from field to tabular in all fields

**My code for single copy:**

```
DECLARE 
  cur_val VARCHAR2(40); 
BEGIN       
  cur_val := Name_In('BLOCK_NAME.SOURCE');
  Copy( cur_val, 'BLOCK_NAME.DESTINATION' );    
END;
```

How to copy values to all fields tabular in oracle forms 10g?

Comment: what is `Name_in`and what is `copy`?

Comment: @hotfix - Its a syntax of Oracle Forms Builder, which is Oracle's proprietary tool for creating GUI applications running on Forms server or Oracle E-Biz Suite

Comment: what do you mean with tabular? Name_In and Copy copies values only in current record. If you need to copy fields in all records selected in block, you have to iterate using next_record

Comment: @Petr Pribyl Tabular have multiple fields and i want copy value from single field to multiple fields

Comment: Does "Tabular" mean `a tab canvas` or `a grid of a single block` ..?

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan tabular form with multiple records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your code like this:

```
DECLARE 
  cur_val VARCHAR2(40); 
BEGIN       
  cur_val := Name_In('BLOCK_SRC.SOURCE');

  Go_Block('BLOCK_DEST');
  first_record;
  loop
    Copy( cur_val, 'BLOCK_DEST.DESTINATION' );
    exit when :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';
    next_record;
  end loop;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but my single field goes empty when button press copy

Comment: can you provide screenshot, how the form looks like just before pressing the button?

Comment: I tested this code with same block and worked successful but when i try with different block copy data from one block to another block tabular form then copy only one value

Comment: first_record and next_record work only on current block. You have to use Go_block procedure to navigate to destination block BEFORE you use first_record

Comment: mean add new line go_block before first_record?